# How to convert a maven plugin into a gradle plugin (maven-surefire-puglin )?

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, maven-plugin

I am trying to use this plugin but with gradle:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST_VERSION</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Instead, if it is not really necessary (because there is any easier way on gradle to proceed) can someone give a clue on how to do it?

Comment: Simple answer to this: Does not work cause Gradle is written in (Groovy/Kotlin) and works completely different than Maven does ..so simply no chance you have to find a replacement for that in Gradle...

Comment: The gradle java plugin already does what surefire does in maven

Comment: @smac89 I'm using the gradle allure plugin to do more or less the same thing: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/java_testing.html#header) on testing Java & JVM projects in Gradle.
It should answer the basic questions around setting up testing in a Gradle project.

However if you are using specific features of the `maven-surefire-plugin` that you fail to replicate, please amend your question with more specific elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to add the aspectjweaver JAR and the JVM arg javaagent while preparing the test compilation to execute the allureServe task and to generate some additional test information on my Allure reports. I could solve the problem using this plugin for gradle: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle